# CSS: Make two column layout with left column fluid (fill all remaining space) and right column fixed (200px)

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image]

I want to make it so that Online Users div stays always at size of 200px while the chat window to the left of it resize to the max size it can taking all available space.

So when window is resized for example - the chat window will shrink but Online Users window stays at 200px, kind of like liquid layout.

left div (chat window) is: entry_window

right div (online users) is: online_window

```
#entry_window{
    border: 2px solid #D4D4D4;
    float: left;
    width: 75%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 1%;
    overflow: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
#online_window{

    border: 2px solid #D4D4D4;
    margin: 1%;
    margin-left: 0%;
    display: inline-block;  float: left;
    background-color: white;
    width: 21.5%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

oh and by the way: for vertical size I made this function to make it in height as big as possible without disturbing bottom part.

```
function autoscale(){
    var v = window.innerHeight - 170;
    document.getElementById("entry_window").style.height= v+"px";
    document.getElementById("online_window").style.height= v+"px";
}
```

Comment: You could use `display:table` and `table-cell` for this or if you can support just modern browsers `flexbox`

Comment: I believe you would have to use a percentage width. So entry_window{200px} and online_window{75%}.   Or you could ise JavaScript on window load and window resize to get the window width - 200 and use that result to set the online_window width

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be easily done with the `css calc` function. However, it depends on what browsers you want to support. check out this [link](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc) so see what it is compatible with.

Essentially, just do this:

```
#entry_window{
    border: 2px solid #D4D4D4;
    float: left;
    width: calc(100% - 208px);
    height: 100%;
    overflow: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    background-color:red;
}
#online_window{
    border: 2px solid #D4D4D4;
    margin-left: 0%;
    display: inline-block;  
    float: left;
    background-color: white;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
}
```

note: you need to `-208` to take the border into account. Also, check out the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p278w4j8/)

Comment: This worked quite perfect, it appears calc() is supported almost everywhere, so going with this solution.

Comment: Pretty much, as long as the user is not on ie8.

Comment: Just nice I always forgot about calc ... Still think in older supports.

Answer (score 3):

This can be done entirely without javascript.  You can use absolute positioning along with defining top/left/bottom/right and width.

example:

```
<div id="lefty">this is left content</div>
<div id="righty">this is right content</div>
```

and

```
#lefty {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: blue;    
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 200px;
}

#righty {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: red;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 200px;
    right: 0;
}
```

See this jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Lyp96yqq/

Comment: This worked kind of, since it uses absolute positioning it makes it quite difficult to adjust any other content below it to adopt to screen size.

Answer (score 3):

With `display:table` and `table-cell` you can do it this way:

```css
*{margin:0;padding:0}

.parent {
    width:100%;
    display:table;
}
.parent > div {
    height:200px;
    line-height:200px;
    background:orange;
    display:table-cell;
}
.parent .fixed {
    width:200px;
}
.parent .flexible {
    background:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="fixed">Fixed Width</div>
  <div class="flexible">Chat Room</div>
</div>
```

Here The Example on [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jwp86rdw/) too.